# A death wish(idiom)

Tags: idioms

Let's say your friend put himself in a dangerous situation that almost got him killed. Can you say:

> WTH dude! That was **a death wish** right there!

Does it mean also as ''you almost got yourself killed''?

Answer (score 2):

A **death wish** refers to a latent desire to die (which goes back to one of Freud's psychological theories about the death-force or death-drive).  When we do something reckless, someone might ask, "Dude, do you have a death wish?" but the reckless act is not itself called a death wish.  We wouldn't say, "Dude, that was a death wish!"

Comment: Also "You must have a death wish."

Answer (score -2):

You are right. It's like you said, the friend has put himself in a very dangerous situation that death seemed as an end or result he "wished" for.

Comment: Answers like "you're right" are incomplete and low quality.  At the very least, I would have suggested the more common version of this idiom.  Even better is to provide references and example sentences.